# By Example Chapter 5. urllib.error.URLError

Tags: javascript, python, django, werkzeug

I am stuck on chapter 5 on the bookmarks tools that I followed in the book.
I am using Django 3.1 and following (I have checked everything almost 10 times) this version on

GitHub: [https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter05]

But I still have this error: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>`

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open

h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request

self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request

self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders

self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output

        A message_body may be specified, to be appended to the request.

        """

        self._buffer.extend((b"", b""))

        msg = b"\r\n".join(self._buffer)

        del self._buffer[:]

        self.send(msg)

 

        if message_body is not None:

 

            # create a consistent interface to message_body

            if hasattr(message_body, 'read'):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send

self.connect()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1399, in connect

self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket

return self.sslsocket_class._create(

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create

self.do_handshake()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake

self._sslobj.do_handshake()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 76, in __call__

return self.application(environ, start_response)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__

response = self.get_response(request)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in get_response

response = self._middleware_chain(request)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner

response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 103, in response_for_exception

response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 138, in handle_uncaught_exception

return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response

six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise

raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner

response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view

return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/bookmarks/images/views.py", line 23, in image_create

new_item = form.save(commit=False)

File "/Users/ricardoponce/Documents/WebSocial/bookmarks/images/forms.py", line 35, in save

response = request.urlopen(image_url)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen

return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open

response = self._open(req, data)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open

result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain

result = func(*args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1362, in https_open

return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1322, in do_open

raise URLError(err)

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

The **debugger** caught an **exception** in your **WSGI application**. You can now look at the **traceback** which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

```
dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

Comment: How does this error get generated, what action(s) cause it?

Comment: it was generated when I clicked in the bookmark it button. here the link in git hub of the exemple. https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, here's what worked for me:

Make sure `Html` and `Css` are loading properly from the **bookmarklet** function of the **bookmarklet.js**. Just print the console.log to verify.

```
  function bookmarklet(msg) {
// load CSS
var css = jQuery('<link>');
css.attr({
  rel: 'stylesheet',
  type: 'text/css',
  href: static_url + 'css/bookmarklet.css?r=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999999999999)
});
jQuery('head').append(css);
console.log('css')

// load HTML
box_html = '<div id="bookmarklet"><a href="#" id="close">&times;</a><h1>Select an image to bookmark:</h1><div class="images"></div></div>';
jQuery('body').append(box_html);
console.log('html')
--snip--
```

Also check if Jquery is loaded or not:

```
 --snip--
  // Check if jQuery is loaded
  if (typeof window.jQuery != 'undefined') {
  bookmarklet();
 } else {
 var conflict = typeof window.$ != 'undefined'; // Check for conflicts
 // Create the script and point to Google API
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' + jquery_version +
  '/jquery.min.js';
console.log('loaded')


document.head.appendChild(script); // Add the script to the 'head' for processing
// create a way to wait until script loading
var attempts = 15;
(function () {
  // Check again if jQuery is undefined
  if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') {
    if (--attempts > 0) {
      // Calls himself in a few milliseconds
      window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 250)
    } else {
      // Too much attempts to load, send error
      alert('An error occurred while loading jQuery')
    }
  } else {
    bookmarklet();
  }
})();
```

}

This will give you a alert if `jquery` is not loaded and you can also see in the console to make sure if `html` and `css` are loaded properly or not.
This could be reason for the error like it was for me.
Also the path which leads to the bookmarked image starts with http://localhost:8000/images not /image.